# Keyboard layout, FN brightness

Tags: keyboard

I have installed ubuntu mate on my Lenovo 15IAU7 and i can not use the FN+F5 and FN+F6 to control the screen brightness. When i press the key combination it does nothing. Other FN keys work ok, like the volume, airplane mode...

I ran **xev -event keyboard** but pressing FN+F5 and FN+F6 outputs nothing. On other FN keys it displays the same message:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  110 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What ways are there to fix this?

---

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as a custom keyboard shortcut.

System settings > search for "shortcuts" > Select Power Management in middle column.

Then check (right column):

*decrease screen brightness

*increase screen brightness

And add custom shortcuts for both

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working. It just won't register FN+F5 and FN+F6 as shortcuts. Could be the same reason  xev -event keyboard  is not showing anything when i press the key combination.